# what is the alternative for element.replaceWith(element.children()) in angular 2

Tags: angular

How to create a optional wrapper inside a angular 2 component template?
In angular 1.X I used a directive with link function

```
......
var domElement=elem.children();
if(attr.myValue == "false"){
     elem.replaceWith(domElement)
}
.....
```

Need to do the following in a component template:

Case 1:

```
<div my-value="true">
   <span>This is a span</span>
</div>
```

Expected output

```
<div my-value="true>
    <span>This is a span</span>
</div>
```

Case 2:

```
<div my-value="false">
     <span>This is a span</span>
</div>
```

should output:

```
<span>This is a span</span>
```

Comment: Why not use `*ngIf`?  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Comment: With Angular 2 it is best practice to avoid manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck *ngIf will remove all children in case of false, but I need children.

Comment: This is done as part of component build, I want to add or remove a wrapping parent based on some data

Comment: Maybe we aren't on the same page. I posted an answer. Let me know if you think that makes sense or not.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Look at the question again - he wants the outer div to be removed, but the children of the div to remain. The link you gave does not help in this case, because using ngIf on the outer div causes the children to disappear, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could do get the same behaviour

```
this.el.nativeElement.outerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do, but this works.